# Django - show error (ValidationError) inside the texfield of the form

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, templates, django-forms

How do I set the error value into the textfield, right now it only show the error above the fields, I would like to show that in my textfield

**Actual display:**

[image: What it show now]

**My Goal:**

[image: What I want]

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms            
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
#from models import StudentRegistration
from django.forms import ModelForm
from promSpace.models import Space
from StudentUsers.models import StudentRegistration
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm  



class MyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    prom_code = forms.CharField(max_length = 8)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if StudentRegistration.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email


    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password and password2:
            if password != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
            elif password == '' or password2 == '':
                raise forms.ValidationError(("The password cannot be blank"))
        return password2


    def clean_prom_code(self):
        prom_code = self.cleaned_data['prom_code']
        prom_code_ver = Space.objects.filter(prom_code = prom_code)
        if prom_code_ver.exists():
            return prom_code
            StudentRegistration.prom_name = prom_code_ver.prom_name
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("The Prom Code Does not exist"))


    class Meta:
       model = StudentRegistration
       fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','gender','prom_code','password')
```

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>


<body>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="/register/" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>{{form.as_p}}</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />

    </form>

    </body>
```

I really don't know how to begin, I've been looking inside the django docs and the only thing I could find was {{ form.field.value|default_if_none:"" }}

Comment: Please explain "display the error message inside the text field"? Do you mean you want to display an error instead of what the user typed in? So if the user typed 100 characters and made a small mistake he would have to type it all over again. Is that what you are after?

Comment: For example, we know that just using {{form}} on html brings the raise form.validationError("Email already exists") if thats the case. What I want to do is to display the error "Email already exist" inside the Email textfield.

Comment: Is like a registration form, if some fields are incorrect then it raise the validationError, and display it inside the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the flash message system? You can display a flash message using the following in your view:

```
messages.error(request,"Changes were not saved.")
```

And in the template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }} /li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Actualy, he's trying to modify this system.

Comment: instead of showing as a list item, he's trying to pass the {{message}} as the input text field value

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for, for now I just want the error message to display inside the textField.